# matplotlib empty legend handles

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, legend

I wanted to add some text to a legend in a matplotib plot in python. I was thinking about creating an empty handle, is there any way to do it? Already tried by using somethin similar to:

```
ax.legend([handle1,handle2,None],[label1,label2,labelEmpty])
```

but legend does not accept the None keyword. ( I get the error $Legend does not support None, Use proxy artist instead.$)

If this is not possible any other ideas?

I am thinking on having something like:

```
 ___________________________
|  handle1  -  label1       |
|  handle2  -  label2       |
|       labelEmpty          |
!___________________________!
```

thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Empty entry and title:

```
ax = gca()
h1, h2 = ax.plot(range(5), range(5), range(5), arange(5)**2)

r = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((0,0), 1, 1, fill=False, edgecolor='none',
                                 visible=False)
ax.legend([h1, h2, r], ['a', 'b', 'c'], loc=0, title='test')
plt.draw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  `title='Line 1\nLine2'` also works.